# Does account association actually stifle growth?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts

Does account association actually stifle growth? Take me for example. There are at least three other SE sites I want to join, but I am discouraged from doing so until I reach 200 rep on a site I'm already a member of. Anyone else notice this? Could this be a problem?

*Possible fix*: Add 100 rep to all of a user's existing accounts also when he hits 200 rep on any site.

Comment: *Note*: When I posted this question I was under the 200 rep requirement for site affiliation bonuses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you discouraged from doing so?  Join now, and once you get 200 rep on a site, you can then remove the associations only to add them right back.  You'll get the bonus when you re-associate.

Comment: Hmmm..Didn't think of that.  Good idea!  I will do that now.  Thanks!